# Llamar Categorias a Productos en SailsJs, MongoDD

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sailsjs

Quería pedir ayuda ya que no sé como integrar mi Objeto Categoría de mi BD dentro de la creación de un Producto para que tome todas las Categorías y las muestre en un *Dropdown* Menú en la Vista `AgregarProducto`.

Sé que necesito usar `Categoria.find()`, pero no se donde integrar exactamente, para que al momento de llamar en mi archivo `.ejs` a la categoría, se desplieguen todas las que estan de la BD.

**ProductController.js**

```
/**
 * ProductController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

module.exports = {

    //Agrega un Producto nuevo
    add: (req, res) => {

        const product_category = req.body.product_category;
        const name = req.body.name;
        const description = req.body.description;
        const quantity = req.body.quantity;
        const price = req.body.price;

        Product.create({ product_category: product_category, name: name, description: description, quantity: quantity, price: price }).exec(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { err: err });
            }
            res.redirect('/product');
        });
    },
};
```